# JMeter : How to increment dates by +1 within date ranges for every iteration

Tags: java, date, groovy, jmeter

I want to increment by 1 day  2 dates at every iteration using Jmeter i.e.

- Date1 : 2014/01/01 (iteration1 = 2014/01/02) , (iteration1 = 2014/01/03) etc
- Date 2 : 2014/09/01 (iteration1 = 2014/09/02) , (iteration1 = 2014/01/03) etc

How can I do it ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I understand you tried your best to make the question vivid to everyone, but there is still a problem apprehending it, at least for me. Can you elaborate again on what you have and what you need?

Answer (score 4):

For JMeter specifics:

1. Add [User Defined Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables) element to set initial date values like

   - DATE1=2014/01/01
   - DATE2=2014/09/01
2. Add a [Beanshell PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor) as a child of the request where you need these updated dates. Put the following code into the PreProcessor's "Script" are:

   ```
   import java.text.SimpleDateFormat; // necessary
   import java.util.Calendar; // imports
   import java.util.Date;

   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd"); // define date format
   Date date1 = sdf.parse(vars.get("DATE1")); // get DATE1 from User Defined variables
   Date date2 = sdf.parse(vars.get("DATE2")); // get DATE2 from UDV

   Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); // get Calendar instance
   cal.setTime(date1); // set Calendar's time to be DATE1
   cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR,1); // add 1 day to DATE1
   date1 = cal.getTime(); // set the new value for date1
   vars.put("DATE1",sdf.format(date1)); // update DATE1 JMeter variable

   cal.setTime(date2); // set Calendar time to DATE2
   cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR,1); // add 1 day
   date2 = cal.getTime(); // set the new value for date2
   vars.put("DATE2",sdf.format(date2)); // update DATE2 JMeter variable

   log.info("DATE1=" + vars.get("DATE1")); // print value of DATE1 to jmeter.log
   log.info("DATE2=" + vars.get("DATE2")); // print value of DATE2 to jmeter.log
   ```

Being executed for 3 times it provides the following output:

```
2014/08/30 10:11:13 INFO  - jmeter.util.BeanShellTestElement: DATE1=2014/01/02 
2014/08/30 10:11:13 INFO  - jmeter.util.BeanShellTestElement: DATE2=2014/09/02 
2014/08/30 10:11:13 INFO  - jmeter.util.BeanShellTestElement: DATE1=2014/01/03 
2014/08/30 10:11:13 INFO  - jmeter.util.BeanShellTestElement: DATE2=2014/09/03 
2014/08/30 10:11:13 INFO  - jmeter.util.BeanShellTestElement: DATE1=2014/01/04 
2014/08/30 10:11:13 INFO  - jmeter.util.BeanShellTestElement: DATE2=2014/09/04
```

1. Refer to the variables as `${DATE1}` and `${DATE2}` where required.

For more information on Beanshell scripting in Apache JMeter check out [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide

Answer (score 1):

In JMeter:

0/ First install [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/):

- Download it from http://groovy.codehaus.org/ , current version as of today is 2.3.6
- Unzip the file and find folder **embeddable** and copy groovy-all-2.3.6.jar in jmeter/lib folder
- Restart JMeter
- That's it !

1/ Add [User Defined Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables) element to set initial date values like this:

```
- DATE1=2014/01/01
- DATE2=2014/09/01
```

2/ The recommended way to do this for **REDUCED SYNTAX, PERFORMANCE and LANGUAGE POWER** is to use [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/) + [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor), configure it this way:

[image]

3/ Paste this code in JSR 223 PreProcessor:

```
 final String DATE_PATTERN = "yyyy/MM/dd";  
 def d1Plus1 = Date.parse(DATE_PATTERN, vars["DATE1"] ) + 1;
 def d2Plus1 = Date.parse(DATE_PATTERN, vars["DATE2"] ) + 1;
 vars.put("DATE1", d1Plus1.format(DATE_PATTERN));
 vars.put("DATE2", d2Plus1.format(DATE_PATTERN));
```

4/   Refer to your variables as `${DATE1}` and `${DATE2}`

5/ Running this Plan show this result:

[image]

For why Groovy is your best choice read this:

- http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/jmeter_performance_tuning_tips/

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

- Function to add a number of days to a `Calendar`:

  ```
  void addDay(Calendar calendar, int offsetDay) {
      calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, offsetDay);
  }
  ```
- Example with 5 iterations (from 2014/01/01):

  ```
  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
  calendar.set(2014, Calendar.JANUARY, 1);

  for (int i = 0 ; i < 5; i++) {
      addDay(calendar, 1);

      // Only for preview sample (if sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");)
      System.out.println(sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));
  }
  ```

The output of the execution of this code would be:

```
2014/01/02
2014/01/03
2014/01/04
2014/01/05
2014/01/06
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

as simple as with Groovy's goodness:

```
Date end= new Date() + 5 // from now till +5 days

for( Date curr = new Date(); curr < end; curr++ ){
  println curr.format( 'dd.MM' )
}
```

gives

```
29.08
30.08
31.08
01.09
02.09
```